# App running doesn't reflect Interface Builder look

Tags: ios, xcode, tableview, uitableview

My app has problems with the layout of a UITableViewCell I customized:

everything looks fine on the Interface Builder, regardless of the device I choose. But as soon as I run the app (iPhone 6s Plus or simulator on any size) I get layout problems:

- All labels are on the same spot
- The description label should truncate at its tail as it does on the interface builder but it doesn't when I run the app

[image: Interface builder on the left, app running on my iPhone on the right]

I am not pasting any code because I did all this on the interface builder, let me know if any further input is needed.

Comment: Looks like you aren't setting the heights for the rows correctly.

Comment: @bpapa why? making them twice as big doesn't help. They are set up to be 75 points big in the Interface Builder. I also give them that size on viewDidLoad(). If I change the value to 150 on viewDidLoad() they get of course bigger, but everything with the labels look just as bad as before: just more empty space

Comment: Did you use constraints?

Comment: sure, otherwise it wouldn't look good on the interface builder on different devices

Comment: Yeah, you're right.